# Having difficulty using ffmpeg to get a sample mkv convert to mp4, and play in windows media player

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, windows-media-player

I have this big 4GB file
C:\katc4d7>dir "WSC KAT.mkv"

```
13/06/2020  00:54     4,293,411,907 WSC KAT.mkv

C:\katc4d7>
```

Here is ffmpeg -i on that file

```
C:\katowice_c4d7>ffmpeg -i "WSC KAT.mkv"
ffmpeg version N-94664-g0821bc4eee Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --e
nable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus -
-enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --ena
ble-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enabl
e-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid
--enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 33.100 / 56. 33.100
  libavcodec     58. 55.101 / 58. 55.101
  libavformat    58. 31.104 / 58. 31.104
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.101 /  7. 58.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'WSC KAT.mkv':
  Metadata:
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6avc1mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.31.104
  Duration: 10:13:18.06, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 933 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      DURATION        : 10:13:18.000000000
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 10:13:18.061000000
At least one output file must be specified

C:katowice_c4d7>
```

Mediainfo on that file

```
C:\katowice_c4d7>mediainfo "WSC KAT.mkv"
General
Unique ID                                : 176298603207404292884266102799528496737 (0x84A1E03B723FDA3FB02350D077720E61)
Complete name                            : WSC KAT.mkv
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 4
File size                                : 4.00 GiB
Duration                                 : 10 h 13 min
Overall bit rate                         : 933 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.31.104
Writing library                          : Lavf58.31.104
ErrorDetectionType                       : Per level 1

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L3.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 3 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                                 : 10 h 13 min
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Title                                    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : Opus
Codec ID                                 : A_OPUS
Duration                                 : 10 h 13 min
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 32 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No



C:\katowice_c4d7>
```

From that, I make a small 10 second sample file

```
C:\katowice_c4d7>ffmpeg -i "WSC KAT.mkv" -ss 0 -t 10 -acodec copy -vcodec copy blahsample1.mkv
```

so

```
14/06/2020  20:55           804,239 blahsample1.mkv
```

ffmpeg -i and mediainfo on blahsample1.mkv

```
C:\katowice_c4d7>ffmpeg -i blahsample1.mkv
ffmpeg version N-94664-g0821bc4eee Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --
nable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus
-enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --en
ble-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enab
e-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid
--enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 33.100 / 56. 33.100
  libavcodec     58. 55.101 / 58. 55.101
  libavformat    58. 31.104 / 58. 31.104
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.101 /  7. 58.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[matroska,webm @ 00000000003e02c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720): unspecified pi
el format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'blahsample1.mkv':
  Metadata:
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6avc1mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.31.104
  Duration: 00:00:10.14, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 634 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      DURATION        : 00:00:10.140000000
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:10.001000000
At least one output file must be specified
```

So that above gives the error or warning or message that

```
> "[matroska,webm @ 00000000004f02c0] Could not find codec parameters
> for stream 0 (Video: h264, none(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720):
> unspecified pixel format Consider increasing the value for the
> 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options"
```

Doing mediainfo on it to show the codecs and container

```
C:\katowice_c4d7>mediainfo blahsample1.mkv
General
Unique ID                                : 80056453567816008795659539662543258381 (0x3C3A4FE6E2791064891BD0F635B8030D)
Complete name                            : blahsample1.mkv
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 4
File size                                : 785 KiB
Duration                                 : 10 s 140 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 635 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.31.104
Writing library                          : Lavf58.31.104
ErrorDetectionType                       : Per level 1

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L3.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 3 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                                 : 5 s 0 ms
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Title                                    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : Opus
Codec ID                                 : A_OPUS
Duration                                 : 10 s 1 ms
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 32 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : -5 s 140 ms
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No



C:\katowice_c4d7>
```

The following gives an error  `Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:1.`  as you can see in output below

```
C:\katowice_c4d7>ffmpeg -i blahsample1.mkv -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 yyy1.mp4
ffmpeg version N-94664-g0821bc4eee Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --e
nable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus -
-enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --ena
ble-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enabl
e-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid
--enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 33.100 / 56. 33.100
  libavcodec     58. 55.101 / 58. 55.101
  libavformat    58. 31.104 / 58. 31.104
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.101 /  7. 58.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[matroska,webm @ 00000000005606c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720): unspecified pix
el format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'blahsample1.mkv':
  Metadata:
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6avc1mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.31.104
  Duration: 00:00:10.14, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 634 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      DURATION        : 00:00:10.140000000
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:10.001000000
File 'yyy1.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:1.
Conversion failed!

C:\katowice_c4d7>
```

and if i try this command `-acodec aac -vcodec copy`, then I get this error

[mp4 @ 000000000298f040] Invalid DTS: 85552 PTS: 82896 in output stream 0:0, replacing by guess
[mp4 @ 000000000298f040] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 85025, current: 82896; changing to 85026. This may result in incorrect tim

as you see in output below

```
C:\katowice_c4d7>ffmpeg -i blahsample1.mkv -acodec aac -vcodec copy yyy1.mp4
ffmpeg version N-94664-g0821bc4eee Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --e
nable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus -
-enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --ena
ble-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enabl
e-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid
--enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 33.100 / 56. 33.100
  libavcodec     58. 55.101 / 58. 55.101
  libavformat    58. 31.104 / 58. 31.104
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.101 /  7. 58.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[matroska,webm @ 00000000001206c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720): unspecified pix
el format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'blahsample1.mkv':
  Metadata:
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6avc1mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.31.104
  Duration: 00:00:10.14, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 634 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      DURATION        : 00:00:10.140000000
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:10.001000000
File 'yyy1.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (opus (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp4, to 'yyy1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6avc1mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    encoder         : Lavf58.31.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 16k tbn, 1k tbc (
default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      DURATION        : 00:00:10.140000000
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:10.001000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.55.101 aac
[mp4 @ 000000000298f040] Invalid DTS: 85552 PTS: 82896 in output stream 0:0, replacing by guess
[mp4 @ 000000000298f040] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 85025, current: 82896; changing to 85026. This may result in incorrect tim
estamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 000000000298f040] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 85026, current: 83424; changing to 85027. This may result in incorrect tim
estamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 000000000298f040] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 85027, current: 83952; changing to 85028. This may result in incorrect tim
estamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 000000000298f040] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 85028, current: 84496; changing to 85029. This may result in incorrect tim
estamps in the output file.
frame=  147 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     794kB time=00:00:10.01 bitrate= 649.4kbits/s speed=43.2x
video:629kB audio:157kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.968342%
[aac @ 0000000000143a00] Qavg: 179.721

C:\katowice_c4d7>
```

When I create this file yyyz1.mp4 it will play in VLC but won't play in WMP

```
C:\katowice_c4d7>ffmpeg -i blahsample1.mkv -acodec aac -vcodec copy yyyz1.mp4
ffmpeg version N-94664-g0821bc4eee Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --e
nable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus -
-enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --ena
ble-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enabl
e-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid
--enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 33.100 / 56. 33.100
  libavcodec     58. 55.101 / 58. 55.101
  libavformat    58. 31.104 / 58. 31.104
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.101 /  7. 58.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[matroska,webm @ 00000000003206c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720): unspecified pix
el format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'blahsample1.mkv':
  Metadata:
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6avc1mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.31.104
  Duration: 00:00:10.14, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 634 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      DURATION        : 00:00:10.140000000
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:10.001000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (opus (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp4, to 'yyyz1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6avc1mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    encoder         : Lavf58.31.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 16k tbn, 1k tbc (
default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      DURATION        : 00:00:10.140000000
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:10.001000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.55.101 aac
[mp4 @ 0000000002972280] Invalid DTS: 85552 PTS: 82896 in output stream 0:0, replacing by guess
[mp4 @ 0000000002972280] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 85025, current: 82896; changing to 85026. This may result in incorrect tim
estamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0000000002972280] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 85026, current: 83424; changing to 85027. This may result in incorrect tim
estamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0000000002972280] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 85027, current: 83952; changing to 85028. This may result in incorrect tim
estamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0000000002972280] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 85028, current: 84496; changing to 85029. This may result in incorrect tim
estamps in the output file.
frame=  147 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     794kB time=00:00:10.01 bitrate= 649.4kbits/s speed=44.9x
video:629kB audio:157kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.968342%
[aac @ 0000000002976700] Qavg: 179.721

C:\katowice_c4d7>yyyz1.mp4
```

If I try

```
C:\katowice_c4d7>ffmpeg -ss 0 -i "WSC KAT.mkv" -t 10 -acodec aac -vcodec copy -analyzeduration 4GB blahsample3.mp4
```

Then still, it plays in VLC, but not in WMP

I have just heard that -analyzeduration is meant to go before the -i,

And I notice mediainfo says AAC low complexity.  I just tried making another file. This time putting analyzeduration before the -i  and using MP3 for audio

`ffmpeg -ss 0 -analyzeduration 4GB  -i "WSC KAT.mkv" -t 10 -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec copy blahsample5.mp4`   It plays in VLC not WMP. I wonder if there's any way I can see if there's anything funny about the file that migh cause that?

but it still plays in VLC not WMP

If I try this command , I do get some interesting output when it converts, I wonder if there is a clue there .

```
C:\kat>ffmpeg -ss 0 -analyzeduration 4GB  -i "WSC KAT.mkv"-t 10 -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264 blahsample6.mp4

....Output #0, mp4, to 'blahsample6.mp4':
  Metadata:
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6avc1mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    encoder         : Lavf58.31.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      DURATION        : 10:13:18.000000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.55.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: 18446744073709551615
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 10:13:18.061000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.55.101 libmp3lame
frame=  300 fps= 57 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1080kB time=00:00:10.01 bitrate= 883.6kbits/s speed= 1.9x
video:914kB audio:157kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.925101%
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] frame I:2     Avg QP:17.81  size:134240
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] frame P:76    Avg QP:20.80  size:  6444
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] frame B:222   Avg QP:26.70  size:   796
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] consecutive B-frames:  1.3%  0.0%  0.0% 98.7%
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] mb I  I16..4: 11.6% 18.2% 70.2%
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] mb P  I16..4:  0.6%  0.9%  0.6%  P16..4: 11.8%  3.6%  3.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:79.1%
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  8.5%  0.8%  0.4%  direct: 0.3%  skip:89.9%  L0:53.7% L1:42.6% BI: 3.7%
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] 8x8 transform intra:29.5% inter:50.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 72.9% 76.0% 48.0% inter: 2.3% 2.8% 0.3%
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 13% 40% 25% 22%
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 17% 25% 29%  5%  4%  4%  5%  5%  7%
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 32% 13%  5%  7%  5%  6%  5%  6%
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] i8c dc,h,v,p: 41% 35% 19%  5%
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] ref P L0: 72.3%  9.5% 13.3%  4.9%
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] ref B L0: 93.3%  6.0%  0.8%
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] ref B L1: 96.0%  4.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000004afb40] kb/s:747.92
```

**Added**

I just tried the -fflags suggested

https://pastebin.com/raw/3pwWWGyV

but it still doesn't play in WMP

I can't paste that content into my question as there's a limit to how much I can put in! But it's at that pastebin link.

This one might be more revealing

`ffmpeg -analyzeduration 4GB -fflags +igndts -ss 0 -i "WSC KAT.mkv" -t 10 -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264 blahsample8.mp4`

https://pastebin.com/raw/na8Q1bNv

I see it says

```
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] frame I:2     Avg QP:17.81  size:134240
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] frame P:76    Avg QP:20.80  size:  6444
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] frame B:222   Avg QP:26.70  size:   796
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] consecutive B-frames:  1.3%  0.0%  0.0% 98.7%
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] mb I  I16..4: 11.6% 18.2% 70.2%
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] mb P  I16..4:  0.6%  0.9%  0.6%  P16..4: 11.8%  3.6%  3.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:79.1%
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  8.5%  0.8%  0.4%  direct: 0.3%  skip:89.9%  L0:53.7% L1:42.6% BI: 3.7%
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] 8x8 transform intra:29.5% inter:50.0%
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 72.9% 76.0% 48.0% inter: 2.3% 2.8% 0.3%
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] i16 v,h,dc,p: 13% 40% 25% 22%
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 17% 25% 29%  5%  4%  4%  5%  5%  7%
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 32% 13%  5%  7%  5%  6%  5%  6%
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] i8c dc,h,v,p: 41% 35% 19%  5%
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] ref P L0: 72.3%  9.5% 13.3%  4.9%
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] ref B L0: 93.3%  6.0%  0.8%
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] ref B L1: 96.0%  4.0%
[libx264 @ 000000000051d600] kb/s:747.92
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decocing time stamps are broken. Try `-fflags +igndts` to regenerate DTS based on PTS:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +igndts -ss 0 -i "WSC KAT.mkv" -t 10 -acodec aac -vcodec copy blahsample3.mp4
```

**Added by barlop**

regarding it still not playing for the OP, anex5 points out "Windows Media Player does not support the playback of the .mp4 file format. Unless you install DirectShow-compatible MPEG-4 decoder packs  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316992/file-types-supported-by-windows-media-player  "

Comment: thanks, that may improve things, though it still doesn't play in WMP for some reason   https://pastebin.com/raw/3pwWWGyV

Comment: Windows Media Player does not support the playback of the .mp4 file format. Unless you install DirectShow-compatible MPEG-4 decoder packs. 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316992/file-types-supported-by-windows-media-player

Comment: I have no idea how I didn't notice that this laptop's default media player didn't play MP4s. But indeed none of my MP4s play!! It must be I need the codec..

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeking from the beginning of a MKV, avoid `-ss` option.

Generate your sample file using

```
ffmpeg -i "WSC KAT.mkv" -t 10 -acodec copy -vcodec copy blahsample1.mkv
```

To generate a MP4 from the sample

```
ffmpeg -i "blahsample1.mkv" -acodec aac -vcodec copy blahsample1.mp4
```

**Added by barlop**

I see that `-ss 0`  done after -i will actually produce a different file, when encoding to mp4, than if it were put before the -i.  `-ss` if used, should be before the -i, and `-ss 0` is superfluous before the -i, and wrong after.

Gyan comments

"-ss used as an output option with video streamcopying causes ffmpeg to wait till the next keyframe after the seek point to begin copying packets. H.264 bitstreams have a configuration unit attached to the beginning of the stream. Some muxers, chiefly WebRTC writers, may write it without a timestamp. In which case, -ss 0 would cause it to be skipped. Leading to the lack of parameters in the extracted file that you saw"

and

"See this line: `[matroska,webm @ 00000000003206c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720): unspecified pixel format` "

Comment: no doubt -ss 0 is unnecessary when seeking from the beginning, but are you suggesting that the `-ss 0` caused the problem and that's an issue particular to mkv? And what if I wasn't seeking from the beginning?

Comment: -1 No,  that makes no difference at all `fc blahsample10.mp4 blahsample11.mp4` (no differences)  All you spotted was that -ss 0 was superfluous.  Nothing to do with MKV, and it makes no difference to the output. It clearly doesn't and wouldn't solve the problem

Comment: `-ss` used as an output option with video streamcopying causes ffmpeg to wait till the next keyframe after the seek point to begin copying packets. H.264 bitstreams have a configuration unit attached to the beginning of the stream. Some muxers, chiefly WebRTC writers, may write it without a timestamp. In which case, -ss 0 would cause it to be skipped. Leading to the lack of parameters in the extracted file that you saw.

Comment: In the first case I put -ss after the -i (which I guess is as an output option?), which are you suggesting is an issue?  But after that, I put it before the -i, (which I guess is as an input option?), and not an issue?

Comment: You write "the lack of parameters in the extracted file" <-- can you highlight this with a copy/paste showing where the lack of parameters are? like what the lacking parameters look like, relative to what parameters look like not lacking?

Comment: See this line: `[matroska,webm @ 00000000003206c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720): unspecified pix
el format`